# How to display inline icons in menu items?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

### Problem

Here is my select menu after selection. The problem is the icon (the question mark inside speech bubble) appears on a different line from the text ("Question").

Fig. 1. Menu after selection. Icon and text are display:block;

[image: After menu is selected]

### Goal

I want the style after selection to be an inline display. Similar to the way the menu displays the options pre-selection.

Fig. 2. Open menu pre-selection. Icon and text are display:inline;

[image: Menu list items]

### Code

Here's the code.

```
const typeConfig = [
    { value : 'bug'        , label : 'Bug report'      , icon : 'bug_report'      , } ,
    { value : 'positive'   , label : 'Positive review' , icon : 'thumb_up'        , } ,
    { value : 'negative'   , label : 'Negative review' , icon : 'thumb_down'      , } ,
    { value : 'question'   , label : 'Question'        , icon : 'contact_support' , } ,
    { value : 'comment'    , label : 'Comment'         , icon : 'comment'         , } ,
    { value : 'suggestion' , label : 'Suggestion'      , icon : 'feedback'        , } ,
    { value : 'request'    , label : 'Feature request' , icon : 'touch_app'       , } ,
  ]

<FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
  <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} htmlFor="select">{typeLabel}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={type}
    onChange={handleChangeType}
    input={<OutlinedInput labelWidth={labelWidth} name="select" id="select" />}
  >
    {
      typeConfig.map( item =>
        <MenuItem key={item.value} value={item.value}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Icon>{item.icon}</Icon>
          </ListItemIcon>
          <Typography variant="inherit" display="inline" noWrap>{item.label}</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
    )}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Try display `ListItemIcon` and `Typography` inline-block with `vertical-align: middle;` + add a width to `ListItemIcon` so all of the `Typography` are aligned

Answer (score 0):

*Summary from comments*

I'm using tailwind. So I successfully added the `inline` styles as follows.

```
<ListItemIcon className="inline">
  <Icon>{item.icon}</Icon>
</ListItemIcon>
<Typography className="inline" variant="inherit" display="inline" noWrap>    
  {item.label}
</Typography>
```